# Ansible remove \ and brackets from output

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, ansible, output

I am trying to print out the kubernetes version and client version with Ansible however the output comes with slashes and how can I remove the brackets for a more cleaner output?

```
- name: Kubernetes version
  run_once: true
  changed_when: False
  shell: |
    kubectl version
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: kubernetes_version
```

Output:

```
 name: Output
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  debug:
    msg: "{{ kubernetes_version.stdout_lines }}"
```

output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {

    "msg": [

        "Client Version: version.Info{Major:\"1\", Minor:\"18\", GitVersion:\"v1.18.4\", GitCommit:\"e0fccafd69541e3750d460ba0f9743\", GitTreeState:\"clean\", BuildDate:\"2020-04-16T11:44:03Z\", GoVersion:\"

go1.13.9\", Compiler:\"gc\", Platform:\"linux/amd64\"}",

        "Server Version: version.Info{Major:\"1\", Minor:\"18\", GitVersion:\"v1.18.4\", GitCommit:\"e0fccafd69541e3750d460ba0f9743\", GitTreeState:\"clean\", BuildDate:\"2020-04-16T11:35:47Z\", GoVersion:\"

go1.13.9\", Compiler:\"gc\", Platform:\"linux/amd64\"}"

    ]

}
```

Comment: Use custom callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm replacing my original answer, because I was forgetting that
`kubectl version` can produce JSON output for us, which makes this
much easier.

By taking the output of `kubectl version -o json` and passing it
through the `from_json` filter, we can create an Ansible dictionary
variable from the result.

Then we can use a `debug` task to print out keys from this variable,
and I think you'll get something closer to what you want.

This playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: run kubectl version
      command: kubectl version -o json
      register: kv_raw

    - set_fact:
        kv: "{{ kv_raw.stdout | from_json }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ kv.clientVersion }}"
          - "{{ kv.serverVersion }}"
```

Will produce output like this:

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [run kubectl version] **********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "buildDate": "2020-11-14T01:08:04Z",
            "compiler": "gc",
            "gitCommit": "6082e941e6d62f3a0c6ca8ba52927100948b1d0d",
            "gitTreeState": "clean",
            "gitVersion": "v1.18.2-0-g52c56ce",
            "goVersion": "go1.13.15",
            "major": "1",
            "minor": "18",
            "platform": "linux/amd64"
        },
        {
            "buildDate": "2020-10-25T05:12:54Z",
            "compiler": "gc",
            "gitCommit": "45b9524",
            "gitTreeState": "clean",
            "gitVersion": "v1.18.3+45b9524",
            "goVersion": "go1.13.4",
            "major": "1",
            "minor": "18+",
            "platform": "linux/amd64"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: That is a good idea. How would you print the output of the `kubeinfo.txt` file, would that be with the `debug` module? Could you please show me the whole code for my case?

Comment: thanks for the full output. Could you also tell if I only want to output the `gitVersion` how can that be done and not all of the objects?

Comment: You could ask for `kv.clientVersion.gitVersion` or `kv.serverVersion.gitVersion`.